# linux run default program on system start init

Tags: linux, embedded

Hello I have a small netbook with tegra, and I'm trying to create Image Frame when someone turn on a netbook. If I add to init.d Starting script for my graphic application will it run before GNOME desctop, is this good way to do that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a terrible way. Add it to the appropriate `xinitrc` that your distro uses (try looking in `/etc/X11`), before it `exec`s the desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add an entry to your [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) at `@reboot` time. This can even be done without root privilege, for a particular user.

Comment: Except that it won't have access to X this way either.